# Что делает метод forEach?

Tags: javascript

Что делает метод forEach и родственные ему методы?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach ← о_О

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод forEach() выполняет указанную функцию один раз для каждого элемента в массиве.
в этом примере он для каждого элемента выполняет console.log

```
 const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
 
 array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

советую читать MDN для понимания, там все очень понятно расписано